# Getting error while invoking WCF service from MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Getting following error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

This is my WCF web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="AppServerURL" value="AppServer://localhost:5162/WService_618"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
      <service name="ServiceProWCFService" />
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This is my MVC Project's web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <rptBuildProvider>
        <add embedRptInResource="true" />
      </rptBuildProvider>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web,Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState timeout="180"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceProWCFService" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferSize="20000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ServiceProWCF/ServiceProWCFService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceProWCFService"
        contract="ServiceProWCFService.IServiceProWCFService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceProWCFService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        </staticContent>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>      
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WCF service throwing an exception. Change this in your WCF config to get the exception message from service:

```
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

You will want to change this back to false when deploying to production environment.

HTH

Comment: Thanks mate. Now I am getting the exact errors what I need to fix.